# Why am I getting an "Invalid regular expression flags" error?

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I've looked on this site for what "Invalid regular expression flags" is and why it occurs in JavaScript, but this particular case doesn't seem to match the existing questions.

I'm working on a JavaScript-based keyword for Robot Framework (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175683/user-friendly-robot-framework-keywords-written-in-javascript, it's not exactly like that but it uses the same method of calling the JavaScript code). Here's the code I'm using. The Robot Framework Keyword:

```
Click By Text
    [Arguments]     ${text}     ${iteration}=1
    ${tag} =    Execute Javascript  ${ABS_PATH}/${PROJECT}/External/ClickByText.js.ClickByText(${text}, ${iteration});
    Click Element   ${tag}
```

And the JavaScript file in its entirety. I admit to being a noob with JavaScript, which is why I'm fairly certain this error's something simple.

```
function ClickByText(str, desired) {
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var instance = 0;
    var result;
    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
        var thisElement = all[i];
        if (thisElement.innerHTML === str) {
            instance++;
            if (instance === desired) {
                result = "document.getElementsByTagName(\"*\")[" + i + "]";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you happen to know exactly how to make this keyword work, that would be great, but I'm specifically looking for why I'm getting that error. Because I'm using PyCharm and running it like this, I don't even know what line I'm getting it on.

EDIT: Fixed the string creation on line 4.

EDIT: Full text of the error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
```

EDIT: Major revision of the code.

Comment: In the code you've provided, `thisElement` is a string, and therefore doesn't have a `innerHTML` property. It does not produce the error you described, either. there must be a mismatch between your actual code and the code in your question.

Comment: If you're actually "escaping" the quotes with a wrong-direction slash, but `thisElement` is not actually a string (that is, you're doing something like `thisElement = document.getElementsByTagName(/"*/")[i]`) then that could explain it perfectly, since `/"*/` is a regular expression (it matches zero or more quote characters), but the final `"` is not a valid regexp flag (like `g` or `i` to make the regexp global or case-insensitive).

Comment: To add a few things related to your comment, the full text of the error is there now, and the code up there is identical to the code I'm actually using. If that is the case, how would I make `thisElement` an element instead of a string?

Comment: Also, I changed the direction of the slashes, and the result didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive testing of my code, line by line, I found out that the error was in `if (instance === desired)` of the revised code. Like I said, it's something simple. I had one too many equal signs, and the correct code is `if (instance == desired)`.

Based on the comments on my original question and other things I've found on Stack Overflow, I'm lead to believe that "Invalid regular expression flags" is an indicator that an expression, (e.g. `===`) is incorrect for whatever reason. It can sometimes be more complicated than that, based on things I found, but apparently that's the basics of it.

Comment: This did not quite fix my problem with the keyword as a whole, but it did solve a bunch of it. Thanks for the help, @apsillers.